# set vs vector with custom iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, set, containers

I understand this question may be quickly flagged as a duplicate of many other more popular questions, but I'll still ask it:

I need a container that provides duplicate checking on insert (like `std::set`, but allows me to modify elements already present (like `std::vector`). It should also be relatively fast to search for elements (which would prefer `std::set` again). Would it be better to use a vector and perhaps a custom duplicate-checking insert_iterator instead of modifying set elements by erasing and reinserting them?

Thanks

Comment: Move semantics in 0x are the obvious solution to this.  But until then, this is a good question.

Comment: The set of operations that you want are: insertions that will catch duplicates, searches and modifications. But what would be a common usage pattern? What is the expected size for the container? The set will require removal and insertions as a way of performing modifications, but if modifications are few compared with insertions and searches, it might be worth. If the number of elements is small and modifications are frequent, then a vector and linear search might be better... it all depends on what you want to use the container for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is to stop you from using a `std::set`? If you need to modify an element, copy it, erase it, then re-insert.

Comment: Isn't that very slow? At one point, I will need to replace all the elements of a `set<string>` with the same string, but prefixed with some other strings. I fear this will kill performance. (I knwo premature optimization and all, but this can be calculated through the C++ standard requirements for containers).

Comment: @rubenvb In that case, just create a new set, fill it with all prefixed strings, and finally swap it with the old set.

Comment: How frequently do you need to replace every item vs. retrieve them? We can't answer your question because you haven't fully stated the problem. All we can give you is (maybe) the right questions to ask yourself.

Comment: Sorry about the unclarity, I now realise I wasn't formulating the problem correctly (here and in my mind). I now see that I can reform my algorithm to do all the modifications beforehand, and use the set as an easy duplicate check. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using a map?

[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

A map may be a good solution to your problem.

Comment: I need to compare using key=value, it's a `set<string>` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are long and performance is critical then you may be stuck with a custom container that wraps something like a parallel `vector<string>` and `set<string *>`.  Provide a custom comparator for the set so that it dereferences through the pointer to make the comparisons. To modify an element, remove the pointer from the set, modify the string, then reinsert the pointer.

This get a bit messy when you want to remove container elements, so you would want to use some form of lazy deletion.  At that point you are very close to a full-blown free-object pool for your strings.

If you're using a vector of strings in performance-critical code, then watch out for the vector reallocations which would manually copy each string into the new memory chunk.  You can bypass that by watching for an upcoming reallocation, creating a new vector of empty strings (pre-reserved to double size), and then using string::swap on each element to move the old data into the new larger vector.

Things will be much nicer when c++0x move semantics are widely available.